# B&W movie with female creature with fish scale skin

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

As a child in the 60’s I saw a movie with a female creature (mostly human in shape) that had some sort of fish scale skin. As I recall when they showed the creature it was always using the diffused “nylon over the lens” effect making her soft and sort of glowing. She would reside in some sort of “pod” and leave it from time to time to do her dastardly deeds.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What were her "dastardly deeds?"  Please give us every detail you can remember, including where you saw this.

Comment: She killed people. I don’t remember any details on how or why. I was very young and really fish lady killing people is about it.

Comment: Great website to check out is:
www.whatismymovie.com
Just type your search request (however random) and it will display a list of potentials ranked from relevance etc

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. It is not the Night Tide movie. Don't worry yourselves about it. Probably not that good of a movie anyway, just one that I vaguely remember from a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you saw the *Doctor Who* story *[The Underwater Menace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Underwater_Menace)* (1967) ?

Here's some shots of the fish people from that story.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty vague but based on the clues of a murderous fish lady in a black and white movie, from the 1960's, could it be [Night Tide (1961)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055230/)?

From the imdb page:

> A young sailor falls in love with a mysterious woman, performing as a mermaid at the local carnival. He soon comes to suspect the girl might be a real mermaid, who draws men to a watery death during the full moon

All the actual violence happens off-screen so you don't actually see the mermaid/fish-women attack anyone. The fish women spends most of her screentime in a large tank as part of a carnival attraction. It is assumed that she leaves to seduce men and murder them.

It stars a young Dennis Hopper and opens with his character going into a jazz club and watching an extended jazz flute performance (not relevant to the question, it's just cool ).

I know it's a long shot but could this be it? Even if it isn't it's a pretty fun movie, I'd recommend it.

Comment: Night Tide is on semi-permanent rotation on shudder tv... this can't be the movie the OP is describing as, spoiler alert, she is actually just a disturbed  young woman and its actually just a very bad movie that just happens to star a very yound Dennis Hopper